# How to change jQuery UI range slider width

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two range sliders ( slider1, slider2). What I want: when the user starts sliding with mouse on the slider1 then the position( or width) and the value to be same on the slider2 as slider 1.

My current code :

```
<p>
        <label for="amount">Distance</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount">
    </p>
<!--Range slider-->  
  <div class='col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12' id='slide'>

  </div>
  <p>
    <label for="amount2">Distance</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount2">
</p>
  <div class='col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12' id='slide2'>

  </div>

    <script>
         $( function() {
        $( "#slide" ).slider({
          range: 'min',
          min: 0,
          max: 5000,
          value: 0,
         
    });
    $( function() {
        $( "#slide2" ).slider({
          range: 'min',
          min: 0,
          max: 5000,
          value: 0,
    
        })
    
    });
    </script>
```

I know that I have to use the slide event, but I cant change the position of the slide2, thanks in advance

Comment: I've just tried creating a fiddle from you code using jquery ui and cant seem to get the sliders working https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/zLgdy4jb/ if you can fix this fiddle and repost I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slide](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change) event this will get called when user slide the slider then use `slider("value")` to get value and finally set value to both slider.

***Demo Code***:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#slide").slider({
    range: 'min',
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    value: 0,
  });

  $("#slide2").slider({
    range: 'min',
    min: 0,
    max: 5000,
    value: 0
  });
  //on slide of slider call this
  $(".slides").on("slide", function() {
    var selection = $(this).slider("value"); //get value
    $(".slides").slider("value", selection); //set that value in both
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<p>
  <label for="amount">Distance</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount">
</p>

<!-- Range slider 1 -->
<div class="slides" id="slide"></div>

<p>
  <label for="amount2">Distance</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount2">
</p>

<!-- Range slider 2 -->
<div class="slides" id="slide2"></div>
```